Should we change our response to questions asking for recommendations?
Every once in a while (new) users ask for recommendations for learning about cryptography, i.e. this question.
These recommendations include:

Literature


Books
Articles
PDF

Exercises
Webpages
Online lectures
Videos
...

Previously I used to flag these kind of questions as "off topic, we don't accept questions asking for literature recommendations [...]", but I noticed that this flag has been removed.
Should we change something since this flag is no longer in use?

Related: Do we want “literature recommendations” and similar “list/subjective questions”?

It did not have enough support votes

Mark the question as "too broad" or "primarily opinion based" as recommending "good" books / courses is clearly subjective, and listing all of them is ridiculous (and can be had simply by hitting "cryptography" in your favorite online book store - if they are still available anyway).
